# Why I get this error (new Set(...)).slice is not a function?

Tags: stackblitz, codesandbox

I tried to run this code in any of the online code editors but I always get error

> (new Set(...)).slice is not a function

Code:

```
myarray = ['d','s', 'a'];
chr_arr = [...new Set(myarray)];
```

why I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only valid on ECMA Script 6

You need configure in tsconfig.json but online code editor (stackbliz) can't edit

https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Answer (score 4):

you can't edit stackbiltz beacuse tsconfig.json is not available unfortunately .
but for now you can use `Array.from`

```
myarray = ['d','s', 'a'];
chr_arr = Array.from(new Set(myarray));
```

More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from